# CSS file not loading Laravel Localhost

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to load CSS file in localhost but it's just showing white page. I was try to drag and drop file direct to browser and its opened. So file its not empty. and file also open when i use a server and add link to file.
I am using laravel 5.8, PHP 7.2

```
 <link href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

CSS file location /public/css i am getting link in source http://localhost/css/style.css

Comment: What type of web server are you running? Can you show your directory tree

Comment: @EmekaMbah i am running laravel in localhost but for try i was use online server link for test. for example boostrap css

Comment: View source. Look at the `href`. Copy and paste it into your browser and see if it works.

Comment: Use chrome developer tools. View and post your console here

Comment: @ceejayoz the ink already mention in post, The link is showing white page, its not giving error too. <!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="http://localhost/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- //Custom Theme files -->

Comment: If going to `http://localhost/css/style.css` results in a blank page, that's your issue, and it's what you need to figure out. What's the URL to your application? Is it `http://localhost/` or something like `http://localhost/foo/public/`?

Comment: Its localhost, Laravel is in the main folder. SO its http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a file reference error. Check the markup output and compare the file URL against where it actually sits in the directory structure. If they match up, maybe a directory permissions issue?

Comment: I updated my question. And what kind of permission need this file and how to give it?

Answer (score -1):

In css links only asset is working fine... No need to include URL. so try using only asset.

Comment: `asset` is a helper function for `URL::asset`. They should have identical function.

Comment: But in my case i always use only asset and its working fine

Comment: That may be. I'm saying it's not the cause of OP's problem.

Comment: Yes, thats why i said try this.i didno said that this was wrong